# change Arduino I2C bus address continuously

Tags: arduino, i2c, imu

an ADXL345 and IMU9252 are connected to an arduino pro mini through i2c bus. both modules have different addresses.
so i should change i2c address in slave(arduino) continuously to access both modules data.
I need to know how is it possible and if there is any standard solution to manage this situation?

P.S: I'm using [RTimulib](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/RTIMULib/tree/master/RTIMULib) for mpu9252 and [sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/adxl345-hookup-guide#sparkfun-adxl345-library) for ADXL345.
so i should adopt the solution regarding to these libraries.

Comment: If you are using libraries to drive the modules, those libraries should handle setting the I2C address when required. What actual problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the standard [Arduino Wire library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire), you need to use [`beginTransmission`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireBeginTransmission) to begin an I2C transaction:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(address)
```

Just put the correct device address as the argument to that function.